# Imported Classes relationship from one to other

Tags: javascript, node.js, class

O.K..so I kind of figure it out. but I want to make sure its not possible.

lets say I have 3 files:
`index.js` main file,`player.js` player class file,`game.js` game class file.
the main file (index) is importing all the classes. but, I need to have the option to create Game object in both files
example:
`index.js`:

```
var game = require("./game.js");
var player = require("./player.js");
new player("player");
new game("game");
```

`player.js`:

```
module.exports = class Player {
    constructor(arg){
        console.log(arg);
        var asd=new game("ASD");/// <- the problem

    }
};
```

`game.js`:

```
module.exports = class Game {
    constructor(arg){
        console.log(arg);
    }
};
```

how can i call to Game in player class without require game both in the `index.js` and the `player.js` 
I know this will solve it but is there another way without a duplicate require? 
(2 require, one in `index.js` and one in `player.js`)

Comment: Is there a reason you're worried about duplicate requires? Their performance impact is next to nothing, it's pretty much just like another variable name referencing an already-existent object in memory

Comment: Assign `Game` to `global.Game` instead of `modules.exports`, then you don't need to require it anywhere.

Comment: @ponury-kostek Doing something like that when you already have a module system ready to use is an anti-pattern though, right?

Comment: @CertainPerformance right, but this solves his "problem" :)

Answer (score 0):

index.js:

```
var player = require("./player.js");
var game = player.Game;
new player("player");
new game("game");
```

player.js:

```
var game = require("./game.js");
module.exports = class Player {
    constructor(arg){
        console.log(arg);
        var asd=new game("ASD");/// <- the problem

    }
};
modules.exports.Game = Game;
```

game.js:

```
module.exports = class Game {
    constructor(arg){
        console.log(arg);
    }
};
```

Comment: The answer is correct but is actually a disservice. The OP obviously has problems with embracing the concept of modular environment. `Player` class acts as a namespace without a good reason.

Comment: @estus I agree in 100%